# How can I update in database block of text which contains unique serial numbers?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

My WordPress images have post content that is based on a template, but the text contains a unique element.  I want to revise the template.

To simplify:

```
[Block 1]
[Block 2]
[Block 3]
```

I want to change the text in Block 1 without affecting the other two blocks (because it will be tedious to restore the unique serial numbers in 1,000+ files!).

The nomenclature of the link in Block 1 is something along the lines of:

```
<a longlink&ndx=#&etc>
```

The only thing that changes is "#," which ranges from 0 to over 1300.  What I want to do is delete the characters between "=" and "&" — from 1 to 4 characters — so that I could then easily do a search and replace action on the table.

How can I accomplish this?